# How do I make the mstest results available from the TFS build page?

Tags: tfs, mstest

I have a build workflow (xaml) that invokes mstest. My expectation is that there would be a link to the test results available on the build summary page. However, this is not the case.

The build ends with the MSTest command - exits with 1, since there are failures. So, MSTest is the last activity in the workflow.

Something is definitely wrong here. The drop location contains just the workflow logs - no test results. These are found in the TestResults folder, but not in the drop location.

So, my question is - how do I need to wire the MSTest activity so that at the end there would be a link somewhere to the test results?

---

Now the gory details. This is how the last moments of the workflow look like in the activity log (I replaced some stuff with **[...]** for the sake of brevity). Notice the following message at the end:

```
Publishing results of test run tfsbuild@TORSVARCH01 2017-03-02 16:03:43_Any CPU_Release to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection...
        ................Publish completed successfully.
```

But where is it published?

```
MSTest
    Inputs 
        TestLists: 
        ToolPath: 
        TestNames: 
        MinPriority: -1 
        TestSettings: 
        CommandLineArguments: 
        SearchPathRoot: d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\Binaries 
        Platform: Any CPU 
        MaxPriority: -1 
        Category: 
        RunTitle: 
        PathToResultsFilesRoot: d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\TestResults 
        TestContainers: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String] 
        TestMetadata: 
        TestConfigName: 
        Flavor: Release 
        TestConfigId: -1 
        Publish: True 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /searchpathroot:"d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\TestResults" /testcontainer:"d:\b\test\2282\Binaries\BackgroundJobTests.dll" [...] /publish:"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" /noprompt /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/265747" /teamproject:"DFDev" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Release" 
    Loading d:\b\test\2282\Binaries\BackgroundJobTests.dll...
    [...]
    Starting execution...
    Warning: The disabled test 'GetJobReqModels' was removed from the test run.

    Results Top Level Tests
    ------- ---------------
    Passed BackgroundJobTests.AsyncParallelSqlRunnerTest.AsyncExceptionInDoIt
    [...]
    Passed WFMCommonTest.TimesheetApi.UnitTests.TimeSegmentApiTests.Test_RoundTimeOfOneSegment
    1778/5035 test(s) Passed, 3224 Failed, 33 Error

    Summary
    -------
    Passed 1778
    Failed 3224
    Error 33
    ------------
    Total 5035
    Results file: d:\b\test\2282\TestResults\tfsbuild_TORSVARCH01 2017-03-02 16_03_43_Any CPU_Release.trx
    Test Settings: Default Test Settings
    Test Run Error.

    Run has the following issue(s):
    Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'dtSearchNetApi2' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'd:\b\test\2282\binaries\ruleenginetests.dll' was not found.
    [...]
    Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'System.ServiceModel.Web' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'd:\b\test\2282\binaries\utilitytest.dll' was not found.
    One of the background threads threw exception:
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot open database "851qa89" requested by the login. The login failed.
    [...]
    One of the background threads threw exception:
    System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    [...]
    Waiting to publish...
    Publishing results of test run tfsbuild@TORSVARCH01 2017-03-02 16:03:43_Any CPU_Release to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection...
    ................Publish completed successfully.
    Exception Message: MSTest.exe returned an exit code of 1 indicating that not all tests passed. (type TestFailureException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities
```

**EDIT 1**

We are using TFS 2015. The build template is a custom one.

The mstest command line parameters can be observed from the aforementioned sample, but here they are again broken one per line for convenience:

```
/nologo
/usestderr
/searchpathroot:"d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\Binaries"
/resultsfileroot:"d:\b\test\3269\..\2282\TestResults"
/testcontainer:"d:\b\test\2282\Binaries\BackgroundJobTests.dll" ...
/publish:"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"
/noprompt
/publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/265747"
/teamproject:"DFDev"
/platform:"Any CPU"
/flavor:"Release"
```

The `d:\b\test\2282\TestResults` folder indeed contains the trx file and an auxiliary directory. But that is not good enough - I want to seem them online. And mstest claims they are published:

```
Publishing results of test run tfsbuild@TORSVARCH01 2017-03-02 16:03:43_Any CPU_Release to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection...
        ................Publish completed successfully.
```

But what is the address?

**EDIT 2**

I checked the online summary page of the build and the test results link is there, but it is not found on the summary page that one can view in the Visual Studio.

Please, observe the page I can see in the Visual Studio 2015:
[image]

Now the same page when accessed through a browser. Notice the hyperlink to the test on the right side of the page:
[image]

So, I suppose my question can be narrowed down to how can one see this link on the build summary page in Visual Studio?

**EDIT 3**

Here is my almost entire build workflow - http://pastebin.com/9z2UE79E

In order to save some space I removed two pieces:

1. An InvokeProcess activity to upgrade a database
2. An InvokeProcess activity to modify a certain config file.

I do not understand what do I have to do to include the Test Summary on the overall Summary page.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you customize your build process template?

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter - care to provide the rationale?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use the **/publish** option in MSTest activity. Use the **/publish** option to publish test data to the database for the team project collection associated with the project's Team Foundation Server.

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Please, see my **EDIT 2**. Thank you.

Comment: For a default XAML build in TFS 2015, there is test result on build summary page in VS. But from your screenshot, your build summary page  is also customized, I'm afraid you need further customization to add test result section by following article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/06/07/how-to-customize-the-build-summary-page-in-tfs-2012-without-a-plug-in/.

Comment: Since you are using TFS 2015, it's recommended to migrate from XAML build to new tasks based build system. With new build system, you don't need to do customization, just add a VS Test task to invoke Custom Test Adaptors: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/VsTest/README.md

Comment: It is a custom build workflow, hence a custom build summary, I guess. The workflow uses RunWorkflow lab activity to invoke a build and then runs the mstest logic on the produced binaries. If you could include in the answer some concrete details on how to surface the test result link on the summary page - that would be great and would qualify as a complete answer.

Comment: Which version of build process template are you using? You may compare your original template to check test part. By the way, why not just migrate to new build system to simplify this process?

Comment: The test part is identical. That is why it is so disheartening. Some other seemingly unrelated piece of workflow enables it. After all, the test results are present on the browser web page. Just migrate? Is it that simple?

Comment: Anyway, I have included a pastebin link to the workflow.

Comment: You can add a new activity “WriteCustomSummaryInformation” to your build process template, and get test result link from your web access and add it to the new session. Check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2012/06/07/tfs11-rc-simple-build-summary-customization/.

Comment: New build system is totally different from XAML build. It's tasks based. You would need to create a new build definition and add tasks in build definition. Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and we will definitely migrate to it when we are ready. Solving my current problem by migrating is hugely out of scope right now. I suppose I have to shrug my shoulders and go on without my test summary being on the build summary page, because it not being there is a mystery wrapped with an enigma.